# Evil scientist, cyborg cats and lot of unusual things

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remember watching this cartoon on some cable channel in the 2000s in India

**Genres:** Sci-Fi comedy

**Plot:** Evil scientist who works more as comedy relief make cyborg cats, cats are sentient and one of them is protagonist others work for the scientist.

In one specific episode scientist meet his rival who works in animal DNA splicing and makes lots of hybrid animals. I think one of the animals was a dog with a peacock feather or some other animal with a peacock feather. He insults evil scientist and says how animal hybrid is in fashion now and his style is outdated. They do some show off etc.

there was few supporting cast too, one was a creature look like an iron pole.

Broadcast year: Must be the mid-2000s

**Language:** Hindi or English dub

It may or may not be an anime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be *["Cyborg Kuro-chan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_Kuro-chan)*, a comedy anime originally aired from 2002 to 2005.

The main character is **Kuro**, a cat turned into a cyborg by Dr. Go, the classic mad scientist / inventor who wants to conquer the world using a host of cyborg felines. However, Kuro maintains his free will and doesn't want to follow Dr. Go's orders.

[image: Kuro]

There is another cyborg cat named **Mi**, created by Dr. Go to be Kuro's nemesis (but he too turns good, later on).

[image: Mi]

While Dr. Go creates cat cyborgs, his rival **Tendou** prefers using dogs.

I only have little direct knowledge of this, and I couldn't remember or find out a character resembling *"an iron pole"*, but the other details seem to match.